# $R/I$ is not flat for an integral domain $R$ and $I\neq 0$, $I\neq R$?

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra

**Edit**: Mariano already answered in the comment, but then I found  the question [Can $R/I$ be $R$-flat if $R$ is a domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401381/can-r-i-be-r-flat-if-r-is-a-domain?rq=1) that contains the answer too (this was suggested to me by the site now, but for the life of me I could not find the linked question on google, searching this website, or looking at the website's suggestions while I was writing, and I tried really hard. Only after posting I got this suggestion on the right side of the page).

**The question:** I've seen a claim that if $R$ is a noetherian integral domain and $I$ a nonzero proper ideal then $R/I$ is not a flat $R$-module. No proof was supplied, so I tried myself and proved it without assuming that $R$ is noetherian. This made me suspicious, so I'd appreciate it if someone could comment of my proof.

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $I$ be a nonzero proper ideal. Take a nonzero $x\in I$. Then the map $r\mapsto rx$ from $R$ to $R$ is $R$-linear and injective. Tensoring with $R/I$, we get a map $R/I\to R/I$ given by multiplication by $0$. Since $I\neq R$, this map is not injective, and so $R/I$ is not flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works fine and you do not need the Noetherian assumption. Your argument proves the following more general fact: suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $M$ is an $R$-module, and $r \in R$ is a non-zero-divisor such that $M$ has $r$-torsion (an element $m \in M$ such that $rm = 0$). Then $R \xrightarrow{r} R$ is an injection which fails to become an injection after tensoring with $M$, so $M$ is not flat.

In other words flat modules over a commutative ring must be *torsion-free* in the sense that there must be no $r$-torsion for any non-zero-divisor $r$. The converse holds if $R$ is a Dedekind domain, e.g. if $R = \mathbb{Z}$: that is, torsion-free modules over a Dedekind domain are flat.